# PHP recursively merge arrays and overwrite non-scalar values for matching keys

Tags: php, arrays

#### What I'm trying to do

I want to *merge* the following arrays:

```
// array1
Array
(
    [nested] => Array
        (
            [orig] => 1
            [numarr] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 1
                    [1] => 2
                    [2] => 3
                    [3] => 4
                    [4] => 5
                )
        )
)

// array2
Array
(
    [nested] => Array
        (
            [numarr] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 6
                    [1] => 7
                )
        )
)
```

I expect the result to be:

```
Array
(
    [nested] => Array
        (
            [orig] => 1
            [numarr] => Array
                (
                    [0] => 6
                    [1] => 7
                )
        )
)
```

#### What I've tried

I can not seem to achieve the desired result. I have tried both [`array_merge_recusive()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge-recursive.php) and [`array_replace_recursive()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-replace-recursive.php). I expected the latter to work.

```
<?php
$array1 = array('nested' => array('orig' => 1, 'numarr' => range(1, 5)));
$array2 = array('nested' => array('numarr' => range(6, 7)));
print_r(array_replace_recursive($array1, $array2));
print_r(array_merge_recursive($array1, $array2));
```

I believe this is due to the numeric keys and the fact that `array_replace_recursive()` will recursively *merge* non-scalar values.

#### The Question

How can I achieve the desired array *using the PHP array functions*?

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, **show us specifically what you did** so we can help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you. Show us the actual code that you've tried, and then describe what happened and what's not right, and then we can help you from there. Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Comment: do you just want to pick the first key of the first array and the 2nd key of the second array...? that's how it looks like, in which case you have quite easy job there...

Comment: @webeno, it's not that simple. What I have provided is just a sample. Consider if the array structure changes.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary Could you please try to explain it better then...?

Comment: @salathe, of course. Consider if `numarr` were nested deeper.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary, provide the desired output for the case of `numarr` being nested deeper

Comment: @JasonMcCreary why don't you use simple **foreach** for this case

Comment: @JasonMcCreary You may want to provide more / different examples, otherwise it will be very hard to help you further...

Answer (score 5):

I have not found any built-in PHP function that allows you to do this. One note about this custom function is that it preserves associative keys, but re-indexes numeric keys.  That appears to be what you want from the examples.

If we simply privilege the data in the second array over the first, then it will wipe out the `[orig] => 1` entry. If we privilege the first over the second, then we preserve elements 3 through 5 in the `[numarr]` subarray.

So this solution preserves associative keys but replaces indexed keys.

```
<?php
function array_merge_recursive_destructive($aArray1, $aArray2) {
  $aReturn = array();

  foreach ($aArray1 as $mKey => $mValue) {
    if (array_key_exists($mKey, $aArray2)) {
      if (is_array($mValue)) {
        $aRecursiveDiff = array_merge_recursive_destructive($mValue, $aArray2[$mKey]);
        if (count($aRecursiveDiff)) { $aReturn[$mKey] = $aRecursiveDiff; }
      } else {
        if ($mValue != $aArray2[$mKey]) {
          $aReturn[$mKey] = $aArray2[$mKey];
        } else if ($mValue == $aArray2[$mKey]){
            $aReturn[$mKey] = $mValue;
        }
      }
    } else {
      if (!is_numeric($mKey)){
          $aReturn[$mKey] = $mValue;
      }
    }
  }
  return $aReturn;
} 

print_r(array_merge_recursive_destructive($array1, $array2));
?>
```

Comment: Of course, but this only works for top level elements. Consider if `numarr` were nested deeper.

Comment: Ok, so you need a generalized, recursive solution that will re-index. Could you provide another set of test data, so we can test multiple possibilities?

Comment: + Initial tests passed. Will review the code this evening and mark this correct. Based on the initial (*negative*) reaction to this question I ended up going in a different direction. However, thanks for your help. I feel like such a function is useful and became even more curious when `array_replace_recursive()` did not work this way.

Comment: @JasonMcCreary How did your further tests go?